# jQuery slideUp and slideDown on a div with a fixed position?

Tags: jquery, css, slidedown, slideup

I am trying to slide up a header on scroll down and show again on scroll up Can you use jQuery slideUp and slideDown on a div with a fixed position?

Comment: The answer to your question is **Yes**.! For more details, you should add some code-example with the issue you are facing. Learn more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: thanks, am just trying to eliminate problems first of all, I think I am having trouble defining my scrollTop values preventing the slideup from occuring after a certain scroll distance, but I will get there, half of getting it wrong is learning, thanks again

Comment: Sir, your code could help us understand better! We are discussing web-design with visuals here.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the shrink class to be less than what your header height currently is.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $thin = $('#ID of-header');
    var $anchor= 300;
        scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= $anchor) $thin.addClass('shrink');
    else $thin.removeClass('shrink');
});
```